# Partial view displaying error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I created a drop down list in a partial view and I am trying to render that on my aspx page. I am getting  an error:

> `{"Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'."}`

This is my aspx page where I am using the ascx control:

```
<td>
    <% Html.RenderAction("getFilterdData");%>
</td>
```

My ascx control looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<assist>>" %>
<%=Html.DropDownList("Assists", (SelectList)ViewData["Assists"], "--Select One--")%>
```

and my controller code is like this:

```
public ActionResult getFilterdData()
{
    scorerep sc = new scorerep();
    ViewData["Assists"] = new SelectList(sc.FilterData(), "assist_a","");
    return View();
}
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817287/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to help without seeing the entire exception stacktrace. Here are a few tips:

- Make sure that your partial `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<assist>>"` and not `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<assist>>"`. You are using an ASCX partial and inheriting from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` which is wrong.
- Make sure that your partial view is called exactly the same as the controller action: `getFilterdData.ascx` (I see a typo here)
- Make sure that the `Assist` class contains a property called `assist_a` as that's what you are using when rendering the dropdown
- Make sure there is no exception being thrown inside the `getFilterdData` controller action while you are fetching the data.

Here's a working example:

Model:

```
public class Assist
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetFilteredData()
    {
        // TODO: replace with your repository logic
        ViewData["Assists"] = new SelectList(new[] {
            new Assist { Id = "1", Value = "Assist 1" },
            new Assist { Id = "2", Value = "Assist 2" },
            new Assist { Id = "3", Value = "Assist 3" },
        }, "Id", "Value");
        return View();
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.aspx`):

```
<% Html.RenderAction("GetFilteredData"); %>
```

Partial: (`~/Views/Home/GetFilteredData.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Assist>>" %>
<%= Html.DropDownList("Assists", (SelectList)ViewData["Assists"], "--Select One--") %>
```